# Random forest regression on a given interval

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, caret

I'm training a random forest regression model on a dataset that consinsts of values in the range of 0-50. It has many values close to zero and only 500 observations. The R^2 is also small, about 0.25-0.4. 
When I use the model on a new test data set I get predictions exceeding the range of 0-50, how can I deal with that?

Sometimes I also get predicted values only in the range of 10-40 but I'm certain there should be many zeros and at least one 50.

Is there a better algorithm that can handle this problem?

I'm using R and the `caret` package. Thanks.

Comment: Is your output space continuous? Which is to say, should be output of your model be a real number in [0,50], or should it be one of the 51 whole numbers in the set [0,1,...,50]? In the latter case, you may want to try a forest of classification trees instead of regression trees.

Comment: @LCialdella thanks for your answer. Indeed I do have only integer numbers from 1..50. But I don't have enough training material for every "class" if I treat the problem this way. I have many observations for zeros but for many integers I have no oberservation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `trainControl` function has an argument called `predictionBounds` that will truncate predictions within a range of your choosing.

However, you might think about using some sort of transformation of the data to map `[0-40] -> [-Inf, Inf]`. I think that doing this will produce better models. `log(y+1)` maybe?